# Severity-'Error', Description-'Spot Dimension does not lie on its reference', Resolution-'Delete Element(s)'

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to run a plugin using Design Automation in a Revit file. The Revit file it's in BIM 360 and it has cloud links to other Revit files in the same BIM360 project. It also has Topography links coming from C3D files.

When the file tries to open I get this error:

```
Severity-'Error', Description-'Spot Dimension does not lie on its reference', Resolution-'Delete Element(s)'.
```

The full report is here:

```
[07/11/2023 14:00:21] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[GetSheetsApp].path)\""
]
"Settings":{
  "dasOpenNetwork": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f"
"ActivityId":"H2T2ElrwMLlyouCRWb09bXHWJanAz0fW.GetSheets+GSA_KmNrPgjxx05IguTsq7jFWZ8bAAGk2fUH"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit_2022!111"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"H2T2ElrwMLlyouCRWb09bXHWJanAz0fW.GetSheetsApp!3"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "rvtFile": {
    "localName": "$(rvtFile)",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:swpkt5090XbHBt8BFu7M+btzrZ0=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Masked:wNp1VBkUJWCPogw9kYHRchfhSrw="
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "localName": "sheets.json",
    "url": "http://a76ef21391cb-3916732089906226749.ngrok-free.app/Masked:oMa+dRaSyr/2TeHJJAMznCLDNQ0=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"KmNrPgjxx05IguTsq7jFWZ8bAAGk2fUH\"},\"scope\":\"data:read\",\"expires_in\":3545,\"client_id\":\"KmNrPgjxx05IguTsq7jFWZ8bAAGk2fUH\"}",
      "x-ads-gateway-secret": "Masked:F6VCvje5cIP0zOGCxgARjmSopQI="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[07/11/2023 14:00:21] Starting work item aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f
[07/11/2023 14:00:21] Start download phase.
[07/11/2023 14:00:21] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/ea9e0a8d-0bc7-468f-b8ff-e9839a33b03c.rvt?scopes=b360project.34444055-460b-4282-906d-1418ee4f98bc,O2tenant.5166051'
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/ea9e0a8d-0bc7-468f-b8ff-e9839a33b03c.rvt?scopes=b360project.34444055-460b-4282-906d-1418ee4f98bc,O2tenant.5166051,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f\ea6b75b0-19b0-460f-b6d2-e7f217bd4ebe.rvt,BytesDownloaded=338051072,Duration=9395ms
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] End download phase successfully.
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f\ea6b75b0-19b0-460f-b6d2-e7f217bd4ebe.rvt" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\7502fde4944b40cb4f3a12af6b0cd18c.H2T2ElrwMLlyouCRWb09bXHWJanAz0fW.GetSheetsApp[3].package"]
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Start script phase.
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Start Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] ====== Revit is running: revitcoreconsole ======
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Current Exe path: T:\Aces\AcesRoot\22.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Echoing command line args:
[07/11/2023 14:00:31]   0:/i
[07/11/2023 14:00:31]   1:T:\Aces\Jobs\aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f\ea6b75b0-19b0-460f-b6d2-e7f217bd4ebe.rvt
[07/11/2023 14:00:31]   2:/al
[07/11/2023 14:00:31]   3:T:\Aces\Applications\7502fde4944b40cb4f3a12af6b0cd18c.H2T2ElrwMLlyouCRWb09bXHWJanAz0fW.GetSheetsApp[3].package
[07/11/2023 14:00:31]   4:/isolate
[07/11/2023 14:00:31]   5:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f
[07/11/2023 14:00:31]   6:T:\Aces\Jobs\aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f\userdata
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config)
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[07/11/2023 14:00:31] Loading RCE ....
[07/11/2023 14:00:42] Running user application....
[07/11/2023 14:00:42] Found an addIn for registration: GetSheets.addin
[07/11/2023 14:00:42] Language not specified, using English-United States(ENU) as default.
[07/11/2023 14:00:50] Get RCE: (VersionBuild) 22.1.40.31 (VersionNumber) 2022 (SubVersionNumber) 2022.1.4
[07/11/2023 14:02:34] Failure #0: FailureDefinitionId-'4d341cec-b2eb-401e-8fc0-c82ed623c9aa', Severity-'Error', Description-'Spot Dimension does not lie on its reference', Resolution-'Delete Element(s)'.
[07/11/2023 14:02:34] Failure: Unable to continue because of posted errors. Rolling back transaction.
[07/11/2023 14:02:39] Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException: Opening was canceled.
[07/11/2023 14:02:39]    at Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(ModelPath modelPath, OpenOptions openOptions)
[07/11/2023 14:02:39]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationData..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[07/11/2023 14:02:39]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[07/11/2023 14:02:39]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationBridge.SetDesignAutomationReady(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[07/11/2023 14:02:39]    at RevitCoreEngineTest.RceConsoleApplication.Program.UserMain(CommandLineArgs cl)
[07/11/2023 14:02:43] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[07/11/2023 14:02:43] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[07/11/2023 14:02:43] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[07/11/2023 14:02:45] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/11/2023 14:02:45] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[07/11/2023 14:02:45] End script phase.
[07/11/2023 14:02:45] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[07/11/2023 14:02:45] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[07/11/2023 14:02:45] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/KmNrPgjxx05IguTsq7jFWZ8bAAGk2fUH/aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEYaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIF2neQpbSE0wSaGbCRdpduZHjkZyZ%2F00EZuUV1AXUpUoAiEA7V8coLLrQXTnt9XnJqZutlJb6HGzlm4vg4BwxaWbVo0qiQMIv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDPVA8yL4Bu8RWgFv3SrdAm0ComDzBEdfz3sSdKQAVFhrHvX7kw01m1oK2mHNXE8txjsU0f%2BVN232KXo5sUQbMvRpdJxyUHjEjvXCf105AMAht%2B2H1yWX%2BEzK8Y%2BLbK%2FSfvQOOdyX3JWnzytSY%2Bb2uB7r484gcSXH2ri4ZKth8aR8TbdhrYSF5zv%2Bcs1nXNRNnEmOAvll6BAoaHZObMsysrXeBqg7%2BsgyGCBkHo2KsQ991wabmiGulMW1%2F9hJOyArxTrjrrY9LH2IiuECkGRBN7XvW48JUWx89e4hKJ4MkKRKAyb%2FD7NBr2rBhJYc0M0hhLRX77XD2lxLJIyviQcnSBnQg%2BWYNkGSavjGuunTUU%2BsQ8i84lBihhAy%2Buth5oV9NMDnGIepnPFHxOqNDppg%2BTGZlq1bjNwPKNzEUkdLaPVip6g7zRdKT1f5qaCEj%2FnYviZ8OQ3Yawaa3pOS4u8cSF7Cf0WDTDnK4aqILvAw5bC1pQY6ngG4R%2BUWDZ5FrNcs%2BXWxNnXPR17%2FmmcFU1a%2FW3%2BK03G14SPNYC5S9Xrtw075RLjQ3GJ%2FJ8QqSblE3jn8Nv46PcGg%2FH8UsuHvx6wfwCgiBYcztK9FInfi7PicuXf1jUgf7c2VRx5onJ6RqZf7D0ClnMn7iHfbeswWbSRfLkUWg2QsB6SgRjV03kH7GHRn%2BSQsY90BZH89hvHGjEmC6G5FHg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3BYIN6C46/20230711/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230711T140021Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=56f1cda1d4fd6e4d5c9e49158359be25a0b130fb77c1a53eb94d481b53051898",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-07-11T14:00:21.4824588Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-07-11T14:00:21.6508802Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-07-11T14:00:31.3763771Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-07-11T14:02:45.3811963Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 338051072
  },
  "id": "aff5d917ec65435f805f6bb0fa5e9f1f"
}
```

I wonder if the problem is the Revit file cannot read the links, because when I open the file from a Revit instance I'm not getting that error.

Comment: We do not have Desktop Connector support for CAD / Topo links in DA.

Comment: @RahulBhobe oh, bad news then. In that case is not suitable to run any DA plugin in a file like this?. Any other solution that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with our research, the link relationship is not exposed to Data Management API, either. So, there seems to be no other way to load the links added via Desktop Connector at this moment.

Therefore, we logged a wishlist item RVTDA-2000 for supporting Desktop Connector in DA. Please remember this wishlist item id for future reference, and we will an announcement on our official blog once it is released in the future. So, please stay tuned to our blog. Thanks!